# Sorting issue NL vs. DE machine

Tags: excel, sorting, sequence

I have an Excel sheet with in 'column A' a technical code (type: text). In 'column B' I have a formula that counts how many cells in 'Column A' are smaller or equal to them, so I have the relative position and can sort them later on. The formula in Cell B2 =COUNTIF($A$2:$A$443;"<="&A2)

[Screenshot of the Excel list I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVaBl.png)
Within my Excel this works fine, as I got the postion for each cell in 'Column B'. But for my German colleagues this doesn't work for some reason. See screenshot below. ID 4062.2.1 does not get position 6 but for some reason a 0.

[Error in German Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPtJV.png)
So my question is: Does someone know why this sorting doesn't work on all machines? And do you have a solution, maybe another formula that I could try?

Comment: The DE-DE machine seems to be using the comma as the decimal point.

Comment: I was thinking that as well, but the type of the cells in column A is text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is if `A2` contains `4062.2.1` then this is a date format in Germany. It is February, 1. 4062. So `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$443;"<="&A2)` leads to `<=4062.2.1` as the criterion because of the concatenation `"<="&A2`. And this is the same as `<=789688`, which is the date value of 4062-2-1.

As far as I know there is no way around except **not** using that kind of ID formats which can be in conflict with numbers or dates if you wants using `COUNTIF` which needs concatenating the criterion.

In your special case you could try

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$443<>"")*($A$2:$A$443<=A2))`

This does not need any concatenation.

Comment: Many thanks! I first want to replace the dots (.) for an underscore (_) in the ID. Hopefully this relatively simple adjustment will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I changed the dot (.) in the ID to an underscore (_) and now it worked also on German settings Excel.

Vielen dank!